# How to record .mp2 formate file using avaudiorecorder in ios 8?

Tags: swift, ios8, avaudiorecorder

all
I want record mp2 file.

var recordSettings = [
AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEGLayer2, 
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.toRaw(),
AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
]

My recording setting as above written in code(swift).
but app crash. I am getting below error,
"The operation couldn’t be completed(OSStatus error 1718449215)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW49 for available recording formats. MPEG Layers I, II and III are not on the list. If you use for example kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC it will work.

Edited: BTW to get some idea what the error code means. For example "1718449215" - convert it to hex string - you will get '66 6d 74 3f'. That corresponds to ascii characters 'fmt?'

Comment: Thanks for reply, but any other way to record in mp2 file (streaming).

Comment: IMO the best shot would be to record raw data using for example AVAudioRecorder and then convert using a third party library such as lame as outlined here: http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1738625/ .

Comment: Thanks, twolame library is useful for me to convert to mp2 format